# How does a washing machine intake solenoid valve control flow rate?

Tags: control, solenoid, solenoid-valve

Our washing machine, an AEG L69480VFL ( [seen here](https://www.ransomspares.co.uk/parts/search/pump/aeg/washing-machines/l69480vfl%20(91491136201)/b/c/m/) )  has a pair of solenoid valves on its water intake looking like this:

[image: Washing machine intake solenoid valves]

(One controls the flow to a tube running to a detergent compartment, the other to a conditioner compartment.)

Running the machine with the top off it's possible to observe the resulting flow through some clear plastic channels above the detergent/conditioner compartments.  And I was surprised to see that rather than just a straight on/off flow control by each valve, at certain parts of the washing cycle the flow seems to be deliberately more restricted and less "gushing"; apparently with the cleverly designed purpose of causing the flow to take a slightly different path bypassing those compartments.

Given that the valves seem to be controlled by AC mains voltages (it says 230V 50/60Hz on them in the above image) and that there's just a couple of wires to each, running from a controller unit... **how would the different flow rates actually be selected?**  It's obviously not controlled by polarity if it's AC.  Would it use a reduced voltage, or something more like PCM?

Exit side view from [here](https://www.ransomspares.co.uk/parts/brands/aeg/washing-machines/l69480vfl%20(91491136201)/-water-inlet-electric-solenoid-valve-2-way/242596.htm)

[image]

Comment: There is no flow control other than on/off with those solenoid valves.

Comment: Fair enough about closure for given reason.  There was actually a bit of an agenda to this question about possibly designing a circuit so that the solenoids could be forced to never be in the partially closed position, but only ever in the fully open or fully closed position (we have low water pressure and I think that would work better for us).  (e.g if the solenoids were DC and 12V, with polarity selecting the mode, a simple rectifier would do it).  However if the things are really just on/off then it seems there must be something else in the machine regulating the flow so it's a moot point.

Comment: Even without that "agenda", the question is clearly about how an electrical design works, not a general use question. Voting to reopen.

Comment: I've only ever seen such valves on/off controlled  **BUT** it would be possible to modulate them in several ways. || "Phase control" with a TRIAC (as used in lamp dimmers) would apply a waveform with less than 180 degree conduction per half mains cycle. This reduces the effective voltage. You'd need a very good understanding of the valve characteristics to use this reliably to control flow. || You still only need the two wires as before. || Other methods  achieve much the same result.

Comment: These valves work by cycling on / off at a specific rate, a poor mans PWM. Decline to reopen.

Comment: As Spehro and others have said - these valves are USUALLY in/off modulated. I've never seen them used otherwise in the last 50+ years. **HOWEVER** AEG are about as competent and experienced as any and it is conceivable that they have implemented wither a phase-controlled or PWM controlled 'soft' opening scheme.

Answer (score 2):

They're pilot valves- just on and off, selecting hot and cold water.

You're probably seeing the operation of the [recirculating pump](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07SWQ9QT1). There's often two pumps- recirculating and drainage.

[image]

Re your comment, I guess that explains the single large port vs. two small ports, which is the opposite of North American washing machines.

Comment: Thanks; interesting.  However a check of the most complete spare parts manifest & schematics I can find at https://www.ransomspares.co.uk/parts/search/pump/aeg/washing-machines/l69480vfl%20(91491136201)/b/c/m/ strongly suggests the machine (an AEG L69480VFL) does not have a recirculating pump, just a drain pump.  If the intake valves are really just on/off I suppose it's not impossible that the drain pump somehow providing suction or not is responsible for the observed differences in flow... I will have to watch the machine operating again with this in mind to conclude anything though.

Comment: I should add that the machine does not have a hot water intake; it's just plumbed in via a single cold water intake which comes in from on the left in my image.  The two valves are to control where it goes from there: either to above the detergent or conditioner compartment, depending on the stage of the wash cycle  Although to finally fill for the rinse stage of cycle, both valves are fully opened at the some time.  Any heating needed is done by an electrical element below the drum; this seems to be the norm for machines in UK&Europe these days.